# Sweet alert - unable to add success sweet alert to simple form submit

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, sweetalert

**

```js
function bindSweetAlertButtonDemo() {
  const swalButton = document.getElementById('sweet-alert-demo');
  if (swalButton) { // protect other pages
    swalButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      swal({
        title: "Nice",
        text: "You've added a task. Click on it for more details",
        icon: "success"

      });

 event.preventDefault()


    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <%= simple_form_for [ @task] do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :name %>
   <%= f.input :description %>
   <%= f.submit :submit, class: "btn btn-danger" ,id: "sweet-alert-demo" %>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

I've attempted to make a form with a submit button to add a task to an index page. On the submit i want a success sweet alert. however the alert first disappeared after milliseconds but that was resolved with a preventdefault(). But now the submit doesnt actually work anymore. any ideas? (I have imported things properly, just didnt add it in the snippet)

Comment: You did not define `event` it should be `('click', (event) => ... `

Comment: did you add <script src='sweet alert URL for js file'></script> file in html for sweet alert, can you please provide us with error to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `event`. You can use `swal`'s `.then` to submit the form if the user clicked `Ok`.

```
swalButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  swal({
    title: "Nice",
    text: "You've added a task. Click on it for more details",
    icon: "success"

  });
 event.preventDefault()
});
```

Demo:

```js
const swalButton = document.getElementById('sweet-alert-demo'), form = document.querySelector('form');
function bindSweetAlertButtonDemo() {
  if (swalButton) { // protect other pages
    swalButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      swal({
        title: "Nice",
        text: "You've added a task. Click on it for more details",
        icon: "success"

      }).then(function(value){
        if(value!=null){
        form.submit();
        }
      });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}
bindSweetAlertButtonDemo();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert@2.1.0/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<div>
<form>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br/>
<input type="description" name="description" placeholder="Description"><br/>
<button id="sweet-alert-demo">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, however this still only stops the issue with the alert displaying for a millisecond. It has now stopped the form from actually submitting the task, and the contents just sits in the input boxes.

Comment: @b.herring You can call `document.getElementById('formid').submit()` to submit the form when you want to.

Comment: sorry im quite new to this. is that 'formid' a placeholder? and if it is, how do i insert my own id into the form?

Comment: @b.herring Enter the `id` of your `form`.

Comment: did you add <script src='sweet alert URL for js file'></script> file in html for sweet alert, can you please provide us with error to check

Comment: @b.herring I have added a demo. Check it out!

Comment: @b.herring No problem.